# Can windows on my desktop be automatically arranged to fill in any gaps?

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop, window-management

On different desktops I will arrange my windows in such a way to provide the most optimal placement for that workflow. The annoying part of this is then adjusting the size of each window to fill in the gaps in between. Is there a tool or command I can use to tell the windows to expand such that all of the remaining gaps are filled for me? This would instead allow me to arrange the windows loosely and have the tedious part of sizing them exactly taken care of for me.

I am using the MATE desktop environment.

An example desktop layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look into tiling window managers. The use-case you are describing in your question is exactly what these window managers were made for. Some more popular options are i3, dwm, wmii, xmonad, awesome, herbstluftwm, etc.

There's a whole subculture in GNU/Linux for people who uses tiling desktop environments, which is also one of the problems: many of these applications are rather involved and have a steep learning curve, and the community doesn't really try hard to make it user-friendly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am already familiar with tiling window managers. In this case I only want windows on a particular virtual desktop to be tiled as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Many programs take a `--geometry` argument or similar.  If the three programs in your screenshot understand this option, you could write a wrapper script to start them with the exact geometry you require.

e.g. I often start my terminal (roxterm) with something like:

```
roxterm --geometry 2560x1346
```

Here, I'm only using the width and height in my geometry setting (because of a bug in bug in roxterm due to a change in the gtk3 library).  You can also specify offsets (i.e. window starting positions).  The geometry spec is `HxW+X+Y`, so `--geometry 100x200+300+400` would open the window at (X,Y)=(300,400) with a width of 100 pixels and a height of 200 pixels.

For programs that don't support a `--geometry` option, you could use `wmctrl` or similar program to change the window properties  - height, width, focused, always-on-top, etc.